# Space in path for copying files in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, space

I want to copy all files created on today date from Folder A to Folder B in batch file.

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)
set MyPath=D:\Temp p
set DestPath=D:\Temp p\1\
forfiles  -m *.* /D %mydate% /C "cmd /c copy %MyPath%\@file %DestPath%"
```

The answer is:

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

But if I change the folder "Temp p" to "Temp" (I mean omit the space) it works fine. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I want to advice you:

1. Enclose paths in pairs of quotation marks!

   Besides the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, there are more characters that are considered as delimiters by command prompt, which are <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`. If you put `""` around all paths in general, you are not going to run into problems with those characters. There are some other characters that are allowed within paths and have special meanings in batch files (like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`); also those become protected when using quotation marks.
2. Always use the `set` syntax `set "VARIABLE=Value"`!

   That way the quotation marks do not become part of the value assigned to the variable, but some special characters like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|` and even `"` do not cause any trouble, and trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>s at that command line do not become part of the value unintendedly. Another great advantage is that you need to care about surrounding `""` only when you expand (read) a variable like `"%VARIABLE%"`, since as aforementioned the `""` are not contained in the value. So you can use a variable even as part of a file path like `"%VARIABLE%\file.txt"` to have the entire path in between `""`.
   Note that this syntax only works when [command extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled, but this is the default for the Windows command prompt anyway, and disabling them makes only sense when you want to execute a batch file that has been written for MS-DOS ([`command.com`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-cmd.html)).

---

So for your code portion (without checking the intrinsic function) the above means:

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do (set "mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c")
set "MyPath=D:\Temp p"
set "DestPath=D:\Temp p\1\"
forfiles /P "%MyPath%" /M "*.*" /D %mydate% /C "cmd /C copy @file \"%DestPath%\""
```

The `forfiles` command constitutes a problem if it is used as you tried, because the value `@file` *includes* the surrounding `""` (unfortunately). So (assuming the currently iterated item is called `filename.ext`), the path `%MyPath%\@file` will look like `D:\Temp p\"filename.ext"` when the variables are replaced by their values. To work around that I added the option `/P "%MyPath%"`, so `forfiles` runs the command after the `/C` switch within the directory given by `%MyPath%`, so you do not need to prepend `%MyFile%` to `@file` but use the latter alone.

As you might have noticed I did not put `""` around `%DestPath%` but wrote `\"%DestPath%\"` instead. This is also a `forfiles` speciality, because you need to escape quotation marks within the quoted command line string (after `/C`) by preceding `\`. Otherwise `forfiles` removes any literal quotes `"`.

Therefore `forfiles` carries out the following command for being executed per each loop iteration: `cmd /C copy "filename.ext" "%DestPath%"` (reusing the above mentioned sample item).

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes in order to find the path:

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)
set MyPath="D:\Temp p"
set DestPath="D:\Temp p\1\"
forfiles /p  "%MyPath%" /m *.* /D %mydate% /C "cmd /c copy @file \"%DestPath%"\"
```

In this way you will escape the space

Comment: it says "ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'p'."

Comment: which version of windows are you using?

Comment: it is tested on windows 7 and windows server 2008

Comment: What if you set the path just like set MyPath=D:\Temp p\ without double quotes and using the backslash at the end?

Comment: I have just tried the following and it works:
`D:\>cd D:\"Temp p"\1`
`D:\Temp p\1>`

Just take care that you only put double quotes around the names, containing the space.

Comment: Thank you Dominique.  The code in the answer should work now!

Comment: Never use quotation marks _within_ a path, always enclose the _entire_ path! `cd` is a bad choice for testing quotation-mark-related issues as this command behaves differently than most of the others (namely, it does not require surrounding quotes in case of contained while most of the others do); `forfiles` is also very special concerning quotation -- see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756918/5047996)...

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this behaviour of forfiles

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to mabe02's answer, you can also use double quotes to escape only the space character.

`For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)
 set MyPath=D:\Temp" "p
 set DestPath=D:\Temp" "p\1\`

Comment: it says : ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'p'.

Comment: Never use quotation marks _within_ a path, always enclose the _entire_ path! see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756918/5047996) for how to put quotation marks properly...